# HP ProBook 470 G5 Notebook - can it use 2x 16GB RAM modules?

Tags: memory

The official [documentation](https://support.hp.com/za-en/document/c05686347) of this laptop indicates that the laptop can take a maximum of 32GB RAM. The configuration however does not show that it accepts 16GB x2.

Can this laptop take 16GB x 2 RAM?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configurations are what HP can send with the laptop, but sure, why not do 2x16GB of RAM. How else will you get 32GB?

Okay now I need to get serious. Normally, the maximum memory size is determined by the BIOS and the memory controller. The maximum size per stick is determined by the memory controller, and also the optimal number of sticks. For your cpu, the optimal number of sticks is 2, the maximum size is 32GB per stick and the BIOS says the max total amount is 32GB. So 2x16GB should totally work, although HP does not have out of the box configurations that have those.

Comment: 2x 16GB RAM working perfectly